# How to create SQLite index for different datatype

Tags: sqlite

When I create index on certain column, index is datatype-aware, however I can store data of any type in any column, but it makes the index somewhat useless if I want to compare column content using different comparison rules, e.g. compare numbers as numbers, not strings.

Example:

```
sqlite> create table foo (key varchar, value varchar);
sqlite> create index foo_ndx on foo (key, value);
sqlite> insert into foo values ('bar', 10);

sqlite> select * from foo where key = 'bar' and value > 9.0;
sqlite> explain query plan select * from foo where key = 'bar' and value > 9.0;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE foo USING COVERING INDEX foo_ndx (key=? AND value>?) (~2 rows)
```

In this case `9.0` gets implicitly casted as `varchar` and two `varchars` get compared, index is used fully, but the record cannot be found.

```
sqlite> select * from foo where key = 'bar' and CAST(value AS REAL) > 9.0;
bar|10
sqlite> explain query plan select * from foo where key = 'bar'
   ...> and CAST(value AS REAL) > 9.0;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE foo USING COVERING INDEX foo_ndx (key=?) (~5 rows)
```

In this case I cast `value` to `real` explicitly and two `reals` get compared, sqlite finds the record, but the index used only partially.

This is understandable behaviour, however can I somehow create index on `foo` table that will treat column `value` as REAL? I've tried using `CAST` in `CREATE INDEX` but got syntax error, I can create view on `foo` table with `CAST`, but index cannot be created on view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are *not* data type aware.

By default, values in the `value` column are treated as text, if possible, because the column has text [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).
Using an index does not change this behaviour.

If you do not want to treat numbers as text, do not declare the column as `varchar`. (Note: you can declare columns without any data type.)

Comment: It seems that defining the column without the type does the trick, comparison work correctly ever without `cast` which kills the index. I'll check a bit more and will accept your answer, if all tests pass

Comment: Defining column without datatype works. Default affinity is still text, but when I use `CAST`, sqlite compare column value as number and keep using index fully, exactly what I need. Thank you.